# How to validate that a Pod is running privileged

Tags: security, kubernetes

I'm trying to figure out how to verify if a pod is running with security context privileged enabled (set to true).

I assumed that '`kubectl describe pod [name]`' would contain this information but it does not appear to.

I quickly created a pod using the following definition to test:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: priv-demo
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: priv-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: priv-demo
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: priv-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      privileged: true
```

Any ideas how to retrieve the security context?  It must be an easy thing to do and I've just overlooked something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
kubectl get pod POD_NAME -o json | jq -r '.spec.containers[].securityContext.privileged'
```